# WooCommerce override woocommerce_cart_product_price

Tags: function, filter, woocommerce, hook, cart

I would like to override the following code in my child theme functions.php file. Because I want the product_price to show "get_price_including_tax" instead of excluding, but the rest of the cart should remain excluding taxes.

```
public function get_product_price( $_product ) {
if ( $this->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
$product_price = $_product->get_price_excluding_tax();
} else {
$product_price = $_product->get_price_including_tax();
}
return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_product_price', wc_price(     $product_price ), $_product );
}
```

Need to switch the "get_price_including_tax()" and "get_price_excluding_tax()", that seems to do the trick, but I don't want to edit core files.

Tried this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_product_price', 'product_price_incl_tax');

function product_price_incl_tax($_product ) {
if ( $this->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
$product_price = $_product->get_price_including_tax();
} else {
$product_price = $_product->get_price_excluding_tax();
}

return apply_filters( 'product_price_incl_tax', wc_price( $product_price ), $_product );
}
```

Which gives me the following error (url removed in error):

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /public/sites/www.t-instyle.nl/paperbag/wp-content/themes/virtue_child/functions.php on line 7
```

If I remove $this-> from the code, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_price_excluding_tax() on string in /public/sites/www.t-instyle.nl/paperbag/wp-content/themes/virtue_child/functions.php on line 10
```

Can anyone help me in the proper direction please? I'm no programmer unfortunately, so I basically have no idea what i'm doing.

Many thanks!

Comment: You got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you already solved this or not, but the first error you listed:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /public/sites/www.t-instyle.nl/paperbag/wp-content/themes/virtue_child/functions.php on line 7
```

Tells you that `$this` doesn't refer to anything. So you kind of need to backtrack to figure out what `$this` should mean. Try changing this line:

```
if ( $this->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
```

to this:

```
if ( $woocommerce->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
```

You may also need to call the global `$woocommerce` before this as so:

```
function product_price_incl_tax($_product ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( $woocommerce->cart->tax_display_cart == 'excl' ) {
```

That should at least get you past the first error and then you can see if things work from there.